Radius and 802.1x windows networking
I am curious how this scenario at AD connected Windows laptop works:

before login to domain account for the first time the computer needs to be connected to Wifi
using WPA3-Enterprise the user enters his credentials before authenticating to the computer itself - how long does it keep users info for wifi connection?
when logged to the computer as a different user, no other wifi authentication is required - then in fact the user sees the network (eg. assigned VLAN) as the other user?

The goal is to clearly identify user activity, even for logging purposes historically.
Another issue is that the user/computer identification is distributed between AD controller, NPS server and DHCP server (Unifi controller in my case). Syslog/EventLog aggregation seems to me as very rough solution.
